# 500 Errors in Dreamhost Running Django under Passenger

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, dreamhost

It's the same old sad song, with new info!

I'm running Django 1.8.3 with Python 2.7.3 as a Pythonbrew install on a shared Dreamhost server; as is common, everything works fine with "python manage.py address.org:8080", but isn't working when the site is navigated to directly, giving a generic 500 Internal Server Error, and the error logs give a premature end of header message.

However, I stuck Paste in there to actually get the errors being kicked back from the trace.

> URL: http://staff.gchrl.org/
>   File '/home/syslib/staff.gchrl.org/staff_site/paste/exceptions/errormiddleware.py', line 142 in **call**
>     app_iter = self.application(environ, sr_checker)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py', line 189 in **call**
>     response = self.get_response(request)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py', line 218 in get_response
>     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py', line 261 in handle_uncaught_exception
>     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py', line 97 in technical_500_response
>     html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py', line 384 in get_traceback_html
>     return t.render(c)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py', line 209 in render
>     return self._render(context)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py', line 201 in _render
>     return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py', line 903 in render
>     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py', line 79 in render_node
>     return node.render(context)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py', line 89 in render
>     output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py', line 674 in resolve
>     new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py', line 779 in date
>     return format(value, arg)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py', line 345 in format
>     return df.format(format_string)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py', line 37 in format
>     pieces.append(force_text(getattr(self, piece)()))
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py', line 270 in r
>     return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py', line 37 in format
>     pieces.append(force_text(getattr(self, piece)()))
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py', line 92 in force_text
>     s = six.text_type(s)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py', line 141 in __text_cast
>     return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/**init**.py', line 84 in ugettext
>     return _trans.ugettext(message)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py', line 327 in ugettext
>     return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py', line 304 in do_translate
>     _default = _default or translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py', line 206 in translation
>     _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py', line 116 in **init**
>     self._add_installed_apps_translations()
>
> File '/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py', line 164 in _add_installed_apps_translations
>
> "The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "
>   AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.

My passenger_wsgi.py is formatted thusly

```
import sys, os
INTERP = "/home/syslib/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/bin/python"
#INTERP is present twice so that the new python interpreter knows the actual executable path
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd(), "staff_site")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "staff_site.settings"
from paste.exceptions.errormiddleware import ErrorMiddleware
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
DjangoApp = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
application = ErrorMiddleware(DjangoApp, debug=True)
```

Comment: your wsgi usually has something like `from staff_site.main import app as application`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Tried that change, and the error remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The original answer below the break *didn't* completely fix the problem. It did act as a temporary patch, though, and pointed me at the right answer.

The actual, fully functional, Django 1.8.3 passenger_wsgi.py should look roughly as follows, assuming a normal, virtualenv installation of Python to freeze assets:

```
import sys, os

INTERP = "/home/<username>/<domain>/public/env/bin/python"
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd()+"public/<your_app_name>/")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "<your_app_name>.settings"

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

---

Okay, so I found the fix. Following Joran's hint in the comment, I looked over the settings.py and came across

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'staff_site.wsgi.application'
```

And realized that Passenger wasn't loading that. Reading the documentation on Django 1.8.3, I saw that it generates it's own WSGI-compatible application, and that the traceback seemed to be failing on actually obtaining a usable application. First I tried putting

```
application = ErrorMiddleware(WSGI_APPLICATION, debug=True)
```

But that failed, with Passenger giving an error that WSGI_APPLICATION was not defined. Thus, I tried a different approach. This is my passenger_wsgi.py file now, but with my information taken out. I preserved the Paste code, to bypass the Django/Passenger disagreement on generating useful errors. If anyone on Dreamhost is having the 500 error issue with Django 1.8.3, this seems to work:

```
import sys, os

INTERP = "/home/path/to/your/install/of/python"
#INTERP is present twice so that the new python interpreter knows the actual executable path
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd()+"<your_app_name>")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "<your_app_name>.settings"

from paste.exceptions.errormiddleware import ErrorMiddleware
import django.core.handlers.wsgi

from <your_app>.wsgi import application as DjangoApp

application = ErrorMiddleware(DjangoApp, debug=True)
```